# Karate API scenario where header string details are needed from browser cookie details to hit a service

Tags: karate

I am using Karate API for one of my eCommerce project. My service integration scenarios are working fine as a guest user but to enhance my validation for logged in user I need header string details from browser cookie details. I will be getting header string details only after user is logged in.

So I need an help in fetching header string from browser and hitting the service with header string captured from the browser. So how can I achieve this using Karate API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this is possible. Refer to this example, everything is clearly explained: [`headers.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/headers.feature)

This line gets the value of a cookie:

```
And def time = responseCookies.time.value
```

And this is a simple way to set the `Authorization` header:

```
* header Authorization = 'some string ' + time
```

There are many other options, but you really need to take the time to read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-header-manipulation

Comment: @ptrthomas : thank you for the quick response. I trying my scenarios with give solution.